# How to install a preview release of Ruby with ruby-install

Tags: ruby-install

Is it possible to install preview releases of Ruby through [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install)? If it is possible, how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
ruby-install ruby 2.7.0-preview2
```